# system partition check failed

Tags: recovery-mode, lenovo

I have a Lenovo A7-30 3300GV tablet, which is stuck on the boot screen.
I have tried the following

1. Did a factory reset from system recovery
2. Wiped cached partition

The problem persists.
I also did a system partition check where I got the following message

> system partition checking ... /system/etc/ctsflagsys d41d8cd98.. Failed! system have been root

What is the meaning of this error.
how do recover from this error?

Comment: What did you do before this error occured? Did you make any changes to the file system or rooted/installed a custom recovery ?

Comment: no, nothing special, I rebooted the device and started seeing this error.